# How to load all files of a folder to a list of Resources in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a folder and want to load all txt files to a list using Spring and wildcards:

By annotation I could do the following:

```
@Value("classpath*:../../dir/*.txt")
private Resource[] files;
```

But how can I achieve the same using spring programmatically?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [ResourceLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) and [ResourcePatternUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePatternUtils.html):

```
class Foobar {
    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public Foobar(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    Resource[] loadResources(String pattern) throws IOException {
        return ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader).getResources(pattern);
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
Resource[] resources = foobar.loadResources("classpath*:../../dir/*.txt");
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Spring

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void loadResources() {
    try {
        Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources("file:C:/XYZ/*_vru_*");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

applicationContext.getResources("classpath:/*.extension"); works for me