# Loading resources from multiple folders in Spring using resourceLoader

Tags: java, spring

This question is in reference with another stackoverflow post - [How to load all files of a folder to a list of Resources in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238746/how-to-load-all-files-of-a-folder-to-a-list-of-resources-in-spring)

I want to load all files from two specific folders using ResourceLoader. I am trying to use ResourcePatternUtils.

class Foobar {
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

```
@Autowired
public Foobar(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}

Resource[] loadResources(String pattern) throws IOException {
    return ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader).getResources(pattern);
}
```

}

```
Resource[] resources1 = foobar.loadResources("classpath*:../../folder1/*.txt");
Resource[] resources2 = foobar.loadResources("classpath*:../../folder2/*.txt");
```

But I need both the resources in a single array. Should I be using something like Java8 stream to concatenate them ?

Answer (score 4):

This could be possible with org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver#getResources interface where you can pass path as parameter.

```
resourcePatternResolver.getResources("classpath:folder/*.xml");
```

Implementation is on ApplicationContext so you can access from this interface also

Comment: let's say i need to add resources from different folders, what syntax works in that case? `classpath:folder1/*.xml:folder2/*.xml` ?